# Custom code-behind forms for content type in sharepoint 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, contenttype

I need to create custom content type derived from TASK content type in SharePoint 2010. The main point here is that I want my custom aspx edit and view forms with code behind to be opened when user opens task of my custom content type. And default forms should be opened for tasks of other types.

How can I do this through Visual Studio 2010 solution?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa544142%28v=office.14%29.aspx) you can find how to Creating Custom Form Templates but the point is the User Controls which use there cannot contain code behind. You must create another User Control with code behind and add it the above mentioned User Control.